# Strange error message : xcode-select: error: malformed developer path ("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools")

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, intel

I have just installed Command Line tools  MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX10.15.sdk on Big Sur 11.2.

When I try to compile with `intel icpc` compiler (Intel SDK update4 2020), I get this strange error message :

```
$ make 

xcode-select: error: malformed developer path ("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools")
```

However, I have done before :

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error is that your system doesn't have Xcode installed. Either you have never installed it on your Macbook or it got uninstalled during any OS update.

So, in order to fix this issue, you must install Xcode. If you are into iOS App development, you can install the complete version and it will solve this issue as well. Download Xcode .dmg file from the Apple developers page.

If you don't use it, you can simply search for the Command Line Tools package for Xcode and download the .dmg file for it and install it. You can download it from the Apple developers page.

If you don't want to download anything and just want to run some commands in the terminal to fix this issue, then here's the command for you:

```
xcode-select --install
```

This is the command which can be run in the terminal and will install the command line tools for Xcode. When you run this command you will be prompted to accept the license, agree with the terms and conditions, etc.

If you are shown that the download requires 7GB+ of space, then be aware you are being forced to download the Xcode Application, in that case, download the .dmg file for command line tools package specifically from the apple developer page.

The above command should fix the issue if it doesn't run the following command too:

```
xcode-select --reset
```

Although this will fix your issue, as a follow-up step, you may need to set the path for the command line tools to run without Xcode.

```
xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

If nothing of that worked and you have the Xcode app installed, then try running the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, my setup randomly broke and this helped.